# Check continuity of linear functional and norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$\mathbb{R}[X] \ni p\rightarrow p' \in \mathbb{R}[X]$

with norm

1)  $\|p\|_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|p(t)|$

2) $\|p\|_{1}=\int_0^1|p(t)|dt$

3) $\|p\|_{\infty}^{(1)}=|p(0)|+\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|p'(t)|$

**My answer:**

This functional is not continuous with respect to any of those norms.

**ad 1)** Consider the family of polynomials $p_n(t)=t^n$ Now notice that at $x=1$ derivative of $p_n$ grows to infinity when $n \rightarrow \infty$. So the norm of the derivative also grows to infinity. On the other hand, the norm of $p$ is equal to 1 regardless of $n$.

**ad 2)** Let $p_n(t)=t^n$ again.  $[0,1]$ $\int_0^1 p'(t)=p(1)-p(0)=p(1)$ Now if we let $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $\int_0^1 p(t)dt$ tends to zero. On the other hand left hand side of our bounding inequality is always at least equal to 1.

**ad 3)** We use the fact that the derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{(n-1)}$ and $p_n(0)=0$ and apply 1).

Can someone verify my answers and tell my if they are good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers are correct; the fact that $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$ suffices to show unboundedness under any such norm.